# Is there a way to get wall posts to display on my mashup web page without using the Like Box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I am trying to create a mashup page for my social networking sights.  Would like to display facebook content on our web page without having to use the like box.  I've searched all over the site documentation but cannot find an answer.  I'm not a programmer so I question whether using the Javascript SDK is something I have the skills for.

It would be helpfull to have the like box without the like button.  Adding the like button would be in violation of our privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a feed of your Facebook page status updates using Feedburner.